# Torrent-stream require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, stream, torrent

Trying to stream a torrent file in the browser by using github.com/mafintosh/torrent-stream with no success. Using the following simple example taken from the manual of the project.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var torrentStream = require('torrent-stream');

        var engine = torrentStream('MAGNET-LINK-HERE');

        engine.on('ready', function() {
            engine.files.forEach(function(file) {
                console.log('filename:', file.name);
                var stream = file.createReadStream();
                // stream is readable stream to containing the file content
            });
        });
    </script>
```

In the chrome console I get the following error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

This error comes from **line 8**. Anyone used this project?

Comment: Are you using Browserify? The error is quite obvious, your trying to use `require` which isn't available in the browser, but in Node.

Comment: torrent-stream is a node.js module.I think the whole script section needs to be run from the server

Comment: Yes, looking at the example at the github page, you are using it in the wrong way. As harryy000 stated, it must be run on your node server.

Comment: Can you guys give me instructions on how can i test it in the browser? I am not exactly a Node-oriented guy. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this library supports a browser, you need to use NodeJS instead. If you wish to stream torrents in a browser, you may like [webtorrent](https://webtorrent.io/). But from my experience, a lot of torrents does not work with it when using in the browser.

You may be interested in [Torrent Stream Server](https://github.com/KiraLT/torrent-stream-server). It is a server that downloads and streams video at the same time, so you can watch the video without fully downloading it. It's based on [torrent-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/torrent-stream) library which you are exploring and has build-in interface.